# Nodejs request with AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I have a nodejs application which is deployed on AWS EC2 instance. In my application I am using REST API as below

```
var options = {
          hostname: 'AWS EC2 Instance IP',
          port: '4730',
          path: '/inbound?name='+obj.name,
          method: 'POST'              
    };
```

For hostname I am using AWS EC2 Instance IP addres.

```
http.request(options, function(res) {
          console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
          console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
          res.setEncoding('utf8');
          res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
            log.info('BODY: ', chunk);
          });
          res.on('error', function(e) { 
              console.log('problem with request: ' + e.stack);
          });
        }).end();
```

but for this I am getting below error.

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: socket hang up
at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1035:19)
at TLSSocket.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

For Public Ip (on EC2 instance) also getting the same error. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on EC2, but the port may be one of the things that you should check.

Do you have the port 4730 open in your EC2 deployment?

Comment: The security group which I used for that all traffic (all ports) are open, but still I have opened manually 4730 port but still it is not working.